# Using minHeapify() to sort array, and extractMin() to return element

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, heap

I'm using minHeapify structure to extract numbers from an array, and uses this method "minHeapify()" to sort my array, and extractMin() to return the element with the lowest value.

It always return the first element first, and it is having trouble computing negative numbers. This is my code,

```
    public class PQHeap implements PQ {

    Element[] eList;
    int size;

    public PQHeap(int maxElms){
        eList= new Element[maxElms];
    }

    @Override
    public Element extractMin() {
        size = heapSize(eList);
        if (size <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Empty Array");
            return null;
        }
        Element min = eList[0];
        eList[0] = eList[size -1];
        // sets the last index in the array to null
        eList[size -1]= null;
        size--;
        minHeapify(eList, 0);
        return min;
    }

    public void minHeapify(Element[] array, int num){
        int l = left(num);
        int r = right(num);
        int smallest = num;
        if (l < size && array[l].key < array[smallest].key){
            smallest = l;
        }
        if (r < size && array[r].key < array[smallest].key){
            smallest = r;
        }
        if (smallest != num){
            swap(array, num, smallest);
            minHeapify(array, smallest);
        }
    }

    public void swap(Element[] array,int parent, int smallest){
        Element tmp= array[parent];
        array[parent] = array[smallest];
        array[smallest] = tmp;
    }

    public int heapSize(Element[] array){
        size = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i] != null){
                size++;
            }
        }
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(Element e) {
        int i = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <eList.length; j++) {
            if(eList[i]== null){
                eList[i] = e;
                break;
            }else{
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    public int left(int i){
        return 2 * i+1;
    }

    public int right(int i){
        return 2 * i + 2;
    }
}
```

The Element array is a must have, so no comments that I should use a arraylist.

When I run the code this is the result:

```
3,
0,
1,
1,
1,
2,
-117,
3,
5,
100
```

Here is the testing class:

```
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Creating a PQHeap with room for 10 elements");
System.out.println();
    PQ pq = new PQHeap(10);

System.out.println("Inserting elements with keys");
System.out.println("  3, 5, 0, 100, -117, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3");
System.out.println("(and corresponding Integers as data)");
System.out.println();

pq.insert(new Element(3,new Integer(3)));
pq.insert(new Element(5,new Integer(5)));
pq.insert(new Element(0,new Integer(0)));
pq.insert(new Element(100,new Integer(100)));
pq.insert(new Element(-117,new Integer(-117)));
pq.insert(new Element(1,new Integer(1)));
pq.insert(new Element(1,new Integer(1)));
pq.insert(new Element(1,new Integer(1)));
pq.insert(new Element(2,new Integer(2)));
pq.insert(new Element(3,new Integer(3)));

System.out.println("Doing 10 extractMins (showing keys and data)");
System.out.println();
Element e;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    e = pq.extractMin();
    System.out.println(e.key + " " + e.data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the question, don't know if i should remove post or let it be, but here is the solution. The insert method didn't follow the minHeap structure:

```
public void insert(Element e) {
    size = heapSize(eList);
    eList[size] = e;
    decreaseKey(eList, size, e.key);
}

public void decreaseKey(Element[] array, int i, int key){
    array[i].key = key;
    while (i > 0 && array[parent(i)].key > array[i].key){
        swap(array,i,parent(i));
        i = parent(i);
    }
}
```